# How can I add a digital pulse generator to a simple LED circuit?

Tags: led, digital-communications, delay, pulse

I have a digital pulse generator in the lab (http://www.thinksrs.com/products/DG535.htm). I want to control a simple LED circuit (battery, resistance and diode) using this digital pulse generator.

I have the socket for the pulse generator, so I can connect the pulse generator to the circuit. I just do not know how to add this socket to the circuit. Where should I connect the two legs of the socket in the circuit?

Thank you.

Comment: Use a transistor. You might have some trouble keeping that pulse timing right, though.

Comment: I think you mean that I should use it as a switch, is that correct? I should connect both legs of the socket to the transistor then?

Comment: One of them should go to the gate/base of the transistor, and the other to circuit ground.

Comment: Incidentally, any particular reason you're using a $4000 piece of precision equipment to switch a (as you put it) "simple LED circuit"? One would think such precision equipment would be paired with proper LED drivers and such.

Comment: @Felthry im assuming student playing with school equipment.

Comment: I kind of see this like Passerby. I gather the OP has a DG535, with 5 ps delay resolutions, and is asking how to connect it to an LED. This is like someone with a Gulfstream 5 asking how to taxi it a few hundred feet down a taxiway. One is surprised when hearing someone with a Gulfstream 5 available asking such a question.

Comment: This equipment is a part of the imaging system. The controller is also connected to a 355 nm 20 ns pulse laser and a CCD camera, and I'm taking some time-resolved images of a very fast fluid jet. I'm trying to set the time delay between the LED light and the laser exactly, so the CCD sensor captures the snapshot in time that I want. I used to do this with an arc lamp with a proper driver, but currently I'm trying to build a new one using LEDs.

Comment: @jonk that happens when you do not know much about circuits

Comment: @EmreTurkoz Thanks. :) That description helps a lot. Would be better in the question. If you feel like up to the idea, I'd recommend you include such details there. It also suggests that a single, cheap BJT switch circuit is going to be a problem.

Comment: @jonk hahah, you're right =) yeah i doubt the response time of the transistor as well. If I trigger the transistor with a TTL signal, I should make sure that it can pass this information with a very short delay (around a few microseconds) in a very robust way. I'm okay with a little bit of jitter, but I need it to be consistent from one pulse to another.

Comment: @EmreTurkoz Yes. Repeatability is key. This may even mean temperature control, as well, if you want consistency within a day (air conditioner turns on, heater turns on, etc.), from day to day, week to week, etc. (If using a simple circuit. There are plenty of ICs that may do this, but you'll have to research them.) Parts also vary from one to another, so you really need to get under management as much as possible. I think you need to post at least these things: maximum allowable trigger delay and the worst case allowable ***variation*** of that trigger delay. Drift over time and temperature.

Comment: The 2n3904 has a transition frequency of 300 MHz. You could change it based on the response you need.

Answer (score 2):

Simple, a NPN transistor and an appropriate base resistor is used with the output.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjdC9N.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: To note, this was posted before op had expanded to explain what they are attempting to do.  Ops target case may require a faster transistor.